# Exporting new project in Eclipse uses values from previous project/export

Tags: java, eclipse

Say I have a workspace with two projects in Eclipse - Project A and Project B. I open the export dialog for Project A and it has all of the default values I expect - 'Description File' is something like `/ProjectA/src/description.jardesc`, etc. Then I open the export dialog for Project B, but some of its values default to Project A's and I have to manually change them. For example, 'Description File' still defaults to `/ProjectA/src/description.jardesc` instead of `/ProjectB/src/description.jardesc`.

Is there a 'correct' way to switch projects so these values are properly set depending on which project I'm currently exporting?

I am aware of saving and using .jardesc files to export, which is what I currently do, but it doesn't help when I have to update the export settings and it still feels like I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Where is the `Description File`? I cann't find it. Are you trying to do a `Runnable JAR file Export`?

Comment: @ZhaoGang Right-click project > Export > JAR file > Next > Next > `Save the description of this JAR in the workspace`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To open the *JAR Export* dialog with the default settings from the `.jardesc` file, **double-click the `.jardesc` file** (instead of opening the dialog via *File > Export...* or via right-click and *Export...*).

The idea of the `.jardesc` file is to store all the settings of the *JAR Export* dialog. A `.jardesc` file is not associated with a single project (one project can contain multiple `.jardesc` files; one `.jardesc` can be used to export code of multiple Java projects). When opening the *JAR Export* dialog via *File > Export...* or via right-click and *Export...* the last used settings are prefilled.